# Cutoff value in linear discriminant analysis with two groups

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, discriminant-analysis

I have a simple linear discrimininant analysis with two classes. Prior probabilitiest are fixed to 0.5 and number of cases is equal between groups. In this case the cutoff value could be calculated as $$\frac{1}{2} (\hat{\mu}_1 + \hat{\mu}_2)^T LD1$$
where $LD1$ is vector of discriminant scores and $\hat{\mu}$ is a vector of variable means in group 1 and group 2, respectively.

Pasted below you can find my R code for simulating data and calculating discriminant scores.

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(406)
# Simulation parameters
mu1 <- c(2, -3)
mu2 <- c(2, 5)
rho <- 0.5
s1 <- 3
s2 <- 3
Sigma <- matrix(c(s1^2, rho * s1 * s2, rho * s1 * s2, s2^2), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
n <- 50
# Multivariate normal sampling
X1 <- mvrnorm(n, mu = mu1, Sigma = Sigma)
X2 <- mvrnorm(n, mu = mu2, Sigma = Sigma)
# Combine into data frame
y <- rep(c(0, 1), each = n)
X <- rbind(x1 = X1, x2 = X2)
X <- scale(X)
X <- data.frame(X, class = y)

# Apply lda()
m1 <- lda(class ~ X1 + X2, data = X)
# 1. linear discriminant
LD <- data.frame(predict(m1)$x, class = y)
```

Then I try to visualize the distribution of the  discriminant scores using the density plot and draw a cutoff.

```
# Compute cutoff value
cutoff <- (t(colSums(m1$means)) %*% m1$scaling) * 0.5
# Density plot
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(LD, aes(x = LD1)) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = as.factor(class)), alpha=0.7, position="identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ylab("Density") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(cutoff, 0), colour = c("red", "black"))
```

The plot look like.

[image]

**My question.** Cutoff line (in red) is moved to the right part of the diagram. Shouldn't it goes through the intersection of both densities (black line)?

Updated plot

[image]

Comment: You do `scale(X)` but then later call `colMeans(X1)` on non-scaled data.

Comment: Anyway, the cutoff is not centered at the intersection.

Comment: Yes, of course, and I wrote to you why. You need to compute the means from the centered/scaled data.

Comment: In my particular case $\hat{\mu}_1 + \hat{\mu}_2 = (0, 0)$, so the cutoff is equal to `sum(m1$scaling) * 0.5`, which is 0.72.

Comment: I don't understand: according to your formula, you need to multiply (0,0) with your m1$scaling -- this should yield zero, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right! But if you reproduce my updated script you will notice that vertical line is still slightly from intersection.

Comment: Figure is posted.

Comment: I think it's perfectly okay now. Why do you expect it to go *exactly* through the intersection point of your smoothed histograms? I mean, the form of the histogram will depend on your smoothing etc., why should LDA care about that? I don't see any problem here left.

Comment: By the way, the question in its current form is not very useful. You updated the code, but did not update the main figure, so a reader looking at your post now will be very confused: What's this first figure? What's this second figure? What are you asking? Etc. Consider tidying it up somehow.